# How can audio player play audio in recycler view?

Tags: android-studio, android-mediaplayer, audio-player, android-audiomanager, android-audiorecord

**my audio player no play audios in recycler view please help me out I am stuck from last week I want to play audios in recycler view**

[image]

Comment: can you elaborate in detail

Comment: @NagoorBhasha I want to make exactly like as mention in screenshot

Comment: i suggest to use single media player for all items , based on item click change the source for media player

Answer (score 0):

This is my recyclerView adapter and you must put your arraylist in this adapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.AudioItemsViewHolder> {

static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
Activity activity;


private final ArrayList<GroupItems> audioItems;//change it() to your items
private int currentPlayingPosition;
private final SeekBarUpdater seekBarUpdater;
private AudioItemsViewHolder playingHolder;
this.activity = activity;

@Override
public AudioItemsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
  //put YourItemsLayout;
    return new AudioItemsViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(YourItemsLayout, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(AudioItemsViewHolder holder, int position) {
if (position == currentPlayingPosition) {
        playingHolder = holder;
        updatePlayingView();
    } else {
        updateNonPlayingView(holder);
    }
}
   private void updateNonPlayingView(AudioItemsViewHolder holder) {
    holder.sbProgress.removeCallbacks(seekBarUpdater);
    holder.sbProgress.setEnabled(false);
    holder.sbProgress.setProgress(0);
    holder.ivPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_play_arrow_24);
}

private void updatePlayingView() {
    playingHolder.sbProgress.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
    playingHolder.sbProgress.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
    playingHolder.sbProgress.setEnabled(true);
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        playingHolder.sbProgress.postDelayed(seekBarUpdater, 100);
        playingHolder.ivPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
    } else {
        playingHolder.sbProgress.removeCallbacks(seekBarUpdater);
        playingHolder.ivPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_play_arrow_24);
    }
}
  private class SeekBarUpdater implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (null != playingHolder && null != mediaPlayer) {
            playingHolder.sbProgress.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
            playingHolder.sbProgress.postDelayed(this, 100);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return audioItems.size();
}
 
    class AudioItemsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
    SeekBar sbProgress;
    ImageView ivPlayPause;
    AudioItemsViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
     ivPlayPause = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sound_btn);
        ivPlayPause.setOnClickListener(this);
        sbProgress = itemView.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        sbProgress.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.seekBar:
                break;

            case R.id.sound_btn: {
                if (getAdapterPosition() == currentPlayingPosition) {
                    if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        mediaPlayer.pause();
                    } else {
                        if (mediaPlayer != null)
                            mediaPlayer.start();
                    }
                } else {
                    currentPlayingPosition = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                        if (null != playingHolder) {
                            updateNonPlayingView(playingHolder);
                        }
                        mediaPlayer.release();
                    }
                    playingHolder = this;



                   
                        PlaySound(YOUR AUDIO FILE);//put your audio file


                }
                if (mediaPlayer != null)
                    updatePlayingView();
            }
            break;
    }


    }


     @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        if (fromUser) {
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    }
}
 private void PlaySound(File filesound) {

    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(activity, Uri.parse(String.valueOf(filesound)));

    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            releaseMediaPlayer();
        }
    });
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
    private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
    if (null != playingHolder) {
        updateNonPlayingView(playingHolder);
    }
    if (outputFile.exists())
        outputFile.delete();

    mediaPlayer.release();
    mediaPlayer = null;
    currentPlayingPosition = -1;
}
}
```

my output:
[image]